# Windows service deploying problem

Tags: .net, deployment, windows-services

I've created a very simple Windows Service projects with [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx). I've build the project, created setup project to deploy it and configured it according to the tutorial information. I've build setup project and installed it. In the target dir I can find it's files so it installed correctly. The service doesn't do anything specific, it just writes a message to event log on startup and shutdown.

The problem is that I cannot see my app on Windows services list (in Computer/Manage dialog) so I cannot control it.

Does anyone have any ideas what I may be doing wrong? My OS is Win7 64bit if thats helpful.

Comment: Did you run the setup project with elevation? Is Visual Studio running as administrator? This might be a problem with permissions/elevation.

Comment: I do have admin permissions on my machine. I'm not gettin any errors during the installation and I guess I would got them if it was permissions problem.

Comment: From Vista on, being a local administrator does not give you full permissions. In order to install a service, the setup process needs to run explicitly with an elevated token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to install it using the installutil.exe utility (under a admin console session)?

```
installutil Service.exe
```

Besides, you need to add an installer component to your windows service before install it using the installutil or the default windows setup project.

Windows services requires more steps in order to be installed, so you will need to run the custom installer actions to register it at the operating system.

Comment: Seems like I forgot to add an installer component. Thanks.